# How to get the first value in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get first file name (`Apple_Desk_1920 x 1200 widescreen.jpg`) in the array `img` declared below. How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
var img = [{
                "image" : "Apple_Desk_1920 x 1200 widescreen.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "aa.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "auroracu4.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "blue-eyes-wallpapers_22314_1920x1200.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "blue-lights-wallpapers_22286_1920x1200.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "fuchsia-wallpapers_17143_1920x1200.jpg"
               }, {
                "image" : "leaves.jpg"
               }, ];
```

Comment: How about reading some documentation about [`>` arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements) and [`>` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_Properties)? That's what documentation and tutorials are for.

Answer (score 4):

It's:

```
var variableName = img[0].image;
```

What you have there is an array of objects. To get an array entry, you use `[]` with an array index (`0` to one less than the `length` of the array). In this case, that gives you a reference to the object. To access an object's properties, you can use literal notation as I have above (`obj.image`), or using `[]` with a string property name (`obj["image"]`). They do exactly the same thing. (In fact, the `[]` notation for accessing object properties is what you're using when you "index" into an array; JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects with a couple of special features.)

So breaking the line above down:

```
var variableName =                // Just so I had somewhere to put it
                    img[0]        // Get the first entry from the array
                          .image; // Get the "image" property from it
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// dot notation
console.log(img[0].image);
```

or:

```
// square-bracket notation
console.log(img[0]['image']);
```

will get it for you, since you have an array of objects.